# jquery ui dialog box not showing close option

Tags: jquery-ui

I can't figure out why a simple jquery ui dialog box won't show the "x" close option. Instead it shows a minimize icon in the title bar.

I'm using this as a reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal

Here's a screen shot:

[image: jquery ui dialog box]

my html:

```
<div id="sibebar-dialog" title="Info">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
  function showDialog(text) {
        if (text == undefined || text == null) {
            text = "Info";
        }
        $("#sibebar-dialog").text(text);
        $("#sibebar-dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            show: { effect: "blind", duration: 200 },
            buttons: {
                "OK!": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }                 
            }
        });
    }
```

Perhaps something in my css settings are interfering here ?

thanks,

Bob

Comment: Can you reproduce this in an online demo such as inbuilt stack snippet or jsfiddle..? what version of jquery/jquery ui, which css file..?

Comment: jquery-ui version v1.11.2; jquery 2.1.1

Comment: it's working fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YAaIEBFsFzvPOPxLB9p5?p=preview

Comment: I figured out that this jquery css theme (version v1.11.20 I linked to was throwing off the dialog styles (I don't understand why) - `<link href="Content/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. It was solved when i added the necessary library:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

It should work for you.